# UINavigationBar custom tint stops button on-tap colour change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I've set a background image for my UINavigationBar using a subclass and overriding the DrawRect method as follows:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    // Drawing code 
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"nav_bar.png"];
    [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];

    // Set tint colour
    [self setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

}
```

As you'll see, I've also changed the tintColor of the nav bar so that my nav bar buttons automatically change colour.

My problem is that when you tap on (must be a proper name for the effect) one of the nav bar buttons, it doesn't change to a different/lighter colour like the default nav bar style.

I'm also using a UISegmentControl in one of my nav bar's and both the segment items appear with the same tint colour so you can't tell which is currently selected, I assume that's the same problem I'm having with the nav bar buttons.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a colour change, but it is just not obvious. You either have to use a different tintColor, and create a custom UIBarButtonItem with custom image

Comment: Ah spot on! I changed the tint colour to red and it does change. I think I may have to go with the custom image for the UIBarButtonItem. Thanks for your help.